# Java Initialize ArrayList From For-Loop

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there a way to combine the two commands below into a single line, where I initialize the ArrayList using the for-loop?

```
ArrayList<KSE> kseList = new ArrayList<KSE>();
for (KSE k : allKSEs) if (k.isKeyPress()) kseList.add(k);
```

The variable `allKSEs` is just a generic `Collection`

```
Collection<KSE> allKSEs = KSE.parseSessionToKSE(ksListString);
```

Comment: If you initialize the ArrayList in your for loop, won't its contents be deleted or overwritten at each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Sometimes readability is worth one or two line more.
(Personally I don't even like the one-line-for-if)

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, you can use the new [streaming syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
List<KSE> kseList = allKSEs.stream()
    .filter(KSE::isKeypress)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Pre-Java 8, what you have is what I would write, though I wouldn't condense the loop into a single line.

Comment: Unfortunately the project is written in Java 7. I don't have the ability to change that.

Comment: I know it's not proper style to condense the loop to one line. I was just trying to make it as compact as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you still use Java 7 you can use Apache CollectionUtils, Apache BeanUtils and the following code:

```
ArrayList<KSE> kseList = CollectionUtils.select(allKSEs, new BeanPropertyValueEqualsPredicate("keyPress", true));
```